# Packaging static files with an Android application

Tags: android

I have some data files that need to be included with my app. I know that I can put the files in the same directory tree as my classes, then open an input stream to the files like this:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)
```

I can also put the files in the `assets` folder, and open them with the `AssetManager`:

```
getAssets().open(path)
```

As far as I can tell, the results are the same. My question: are there any reasons to prefer one approach over the other? I'm talking about concrete technical reasons of the "something will break" variety. I'm less interested in coding conventions or design philosophies.

Comment: Since I am not aware that the Android build tools officially support the former solution, I would recommend the latter solution.

Comment: I used the first approach successfully for a long time till I switched from Eclipse to Android Studio with Gradle build. With that switch loading of files (in my case html files)  didn't work any more. Maybe I would have found a solution but since the asset approach worked without issues and is also the official way to do it, I went with that solution. The question is, why would you not use the asset folder? There's no advantage in mixing code files and data files imo.